# Use Google Maps API to search nearest address from local database

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm in doubt if Maps API has something to do the following: I have a list of places in my local database. Each one with the address (street, city, state, etc...) and maybe with lat/long (I can retrieve this data if needed).
I'm looking for a solution for the case that in a webpage with a Google Maps plotted, the user enters an arbitrary address and get which is the nearest place from that local database I have.

I know I can get this address' lat/long and with some simple math (Pythagorean theorem) I can calculate each distances, but this is not the same when one need to know the distance by driving.

EDIT: I found this solution https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3 and it looks a good one. Is the best approach?

Comment: Would be good if you have the coordinates of your places in your db. I would avoid using XML if JSON is available (and it should be). You can calculate distances *as the crow flies* with the [Geometry Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) (`computeDistanceBetween`), or you can use the Distance Matrix (as stated in the below answer) if you can keep it within the usage limits.

Comment: @MrUpsidown having the coords is not a problem, and they will be in json (BTW, the backend is a node app using mongodb). I have written already some code to calculate the distances and it seemed to be a good solution for my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Distance Matrix API:

[Distance Matrix API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/)

It's easy to retrieve distances with a simple call:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/output?parameters
```

The response is in JSON or XML format depending on your choice. But there are limitations on the number of elements for a single query. You can first choose the locations around the user with a constant radius with simple math and then use Distance Matrix when the number of locations are small enough to send in a query.

Answer (score 1):

The above method takes radius as parameter to search nearest locations.
 Instead of that you can simply get some nearest destinations and pass origin and destination to google direction api to get json or XML data.
 you can then extract driving distance from it.
See the link for more details: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#JSON